# Scraping web with python scrapy and BeautifulSoup?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, scrapy

I need to fetch all articles link from a single page and I tried to do this using both libraries python scrapy and beautifulsoup but actually nothing coming out
Scrapy version

```
import scrapy


class CnnSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "cnn"
    start_url = ['https://edition.cnn.com/business/india/index.html']

    def parse(self, response):
        for links in response.css('span.cd__headline-text'):
            print(links)
```

BeautifulSoup version

```
def links():
    url = "https://edition.cnn.com/business/india/index.html"
    page = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, "html.parser")
    l = soup.find_all('span',class_="cd__headline-text")
    for element in l :
        print(element)
```

both function not printing any data and im sure about the element and the css class
[image]

Comment: either Scrapy or requests will not be able to render JavaScript ! even `CNN` website question answered multiple times before.

Comment: as a hint for `Scrapy`, DO NOT USE `HTTPS` within `start_url `, just use `http` which will converted later to `HTTPS` if supported.

Comment: Yes it answered my question BUT can i relay on this API to build my application ?

Comment: I mean i can't see any information about the API provider

Comment: I already scraped links using scrapy-seleniumRequest according to your url but post is closed.

Comment: do you have it in git ?